# find the distance between two geocodes of same person over the month

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, geolocation, geocoding

I have a set of clients and I usually visit those clients month on month. I used to take geocode of the place during the time of visit. I need to calculate the distance between the 2 geocodes over the month

```
Geocode 
month         Apr                   May
Client code     
CBE2101 10.555770, 76.913892    10.577815, 76.933517
CBE2102 10.557785, 76.915508    10.578504, 76.933517
CBE2103 10.556692, 76.914067    10.577815, 76.933517
CBE2105 10.546950, 76.911546    10.654651, 77.000618
CBE2106 10.556692, 76.914067    10.556004, 76.914067
CBE2109 10.561646, 76.917309    10.553894, 76.912987
CBE2110 10.560599, 76.916949    10.577765, 76.932842
```

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from geopy import distance


wb = pd.ExcelFile("trial.xlsx")
sheet1 = pd.read_excel("trial.xlsx")

Dkm = (distance.distance(Apr,May).km)
```

Using the code I need to get the following result:

```
Geocode     
month          Apr              May                Distance
Client code         
CBE2101 10.555770, 76.913892    10.577815, 76.933517    3.3km
CBE2102 10.557785, 76.915508    10.578504, 76.933517    3km
CBE2103 10.556692, 76.914067    10.577815, 76.933517    3.2km
CBE2105 10.546950, 76.911546    10.654651, 77.000618    18km
CBE2106 10.556692, 76.914067    10.556004, 76.914067    0.80km
```

But I get an error saying
`When creating a Point from sequence, it must not have more than 3 items`